# How to call elasticsearch "aggs" using Spring Data ElasticsearchRepository

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I have one filed called `lastUpdated` in my elastic search bean. this field will hold the date and time when this record was last modified.

I want to get the last updated date and time from a index i.e. max(lastUpdated).

I am using Spring Data `ElasticsearchRepository`, I have written a method in my repository like below.

`@Query("{\"aggs\" : {\"lastUpdated_max\" : { \"max\" : { \"field\" : \"lastUpdated\" } }}}")
public LocalDateTime maxByLastUpdated();`

But I am getting below error at run-time.
`org.elasticsearch.common.ParsingException: no [query] registered for [aggs]`

When I investigated it, I got to know that spring by default adds 
`{"query":<OUR_QUERY> }` in our query.

Does anyone have faced this issue or anyone knows the solution, please help me.

Comment: Did you try to add a match_all query and size 0?

Comment: Why do I need to add match_all?, the same above query is working fine with postman rest call.

Comment: Just to overides spring default. i didn't test that.

Comment: After adding match_all I am getting same error with change in msg `org.elasticsearch.common.ParsingException: no [query] registered for [match_all]`

Comment: I am taking the reference from [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-max-aggregation.html)

Comment: Can you share your new query?